# How to inhibit geom_area in ggplot2 from changing my ylimits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following figure in R, generated using the ggplot2 package which resulted in the following:
[image]

The code to obtain this plot is:

```
df <- data.frame(value_x = c(10,20,30,40), value_y = c(89.3, 89.4, 89.60, 90.1))
myplot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = value_x, y = value_y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
myplot
```

Now I want to fill the area under this curve, but still keep the y-axis scale.
When I add `geom_area(alpha = 0.40)` to the code, the plot becomes the following:

[image]

As you can see, the area runs from 0 to the curve, which rescales the y-axis. How can I inhibit this from happening?

Comment: If you are using an area you should start your plot at y=0. Otherwise it's misleading as you're violating the rule of proportional ink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the use of `geom_ribbon` which understands `ymin` and `ymax` aesthetics. Unlike `geom_area` which gives a continuous bar plot that starts at 0.

```
myplot +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = min(value_y), ymax = value_y))
```

[image]